# glibc make fails inside of chroot enviroment

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

So today I was working on my LFS system using version 7.7 of the stable book. I got to the point where you build the glibc package after doing a chroot into the LFS directory. The package configures successfully, but when i run `make`, the terminal says `Segment fault (core dumped)`. What is causing this and how can I fix it? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 inside a Virtual Machine in VMWare

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. It is happening as I left chroot environment(due to reboot) and re-entered.

The solution is to repeat the construction of virtual kernel file system. Described [in here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/kernfs.html#ch-system-kernfsmount).

Answer (score 0):

> when i run make, the terminal says Segment fault (core dumped)

Run `ldd make` *in the environment in which you invoke `make`* and verify that it is using system libc, and not some part of GLIBC that were left over from previous build attempts.

The most likely cause of a crash when building GLIBC is mixing parts of system GLIBC (e.g. `ld-linux.so`) and parts of newly-built GLIBC (e.g. `libc.so.6`). Any such mixing is almost guaranteed to crash at startup.

Comment: I did this and the last entry points to /tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86_64.so.2
Do I need to restart the whole project?